# Error agregando elemento a vector en C++

Tags: c++

[image: Gestion de Memoria- C++]

Cuando ejecuto el código obtengo este error:

> ->line|90|error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector >::push_back(int, std::vector&)'

Comment: El método [`std::vector::push_back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) sólo sirve para agregar datos al final del vector. ¿No te has confundido con [`std::vector::insert()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/)? PD: Por favor, la próxima vez comparte el código copiando/pegando en la pregunta, no con una captura de pantalla.

Comment: Hola. El código se añade a las preguntas como texto. Puedes echarle un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por cierto, ¿querías insertar un valor o sobreescribir el contenido de esa posición? Si es sobreescribir quizá deberías usar el [operador `[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) o el método [`std::vector::at()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) para sobreescribir un único valor.

Comment: Soy daltónico y me es imposible ver algunos colores en pantalla, es por eso que uso una combinación de colores especial que en tu caso, al ofrecer una captura de pantalla, no tengo. De todas maneras, esta es una página sobre código no sobre capturas de pantalla. Poner una captura de pantalla además de que es más difícil que copiapegar texto, no ayuda en nada porque no puedes compilarla, ni buscar texto ni copiapegar sus caracteres. **PUBLICA CÓDIGO**, **NO CAPTURAS DE PANTALLA**.

Comment: Bienvenido, no te asustes por tanto comentario negativo, es normal, las capturas de pantalla no estan bien vistas, pega el código a ver si te podemos ayudar, saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El método [`std::vector::push_back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) sólo sirve para agregar datos al final del vector, por lo que toma un único parámetro que será el valor insertado al final de éste:

```
 void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

En cambio, todo apunta a que quieres usar [`std::vector::insert()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/), que permite elegir en qué posición deseas insertar el valor dentro del vector:

```
iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);
```

Por lo que tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
if (espacioRestante > 0) {
    std::vector<int> bloqRestante = { 0, direcc + tamanyo, espacioRestante, 0 };
    // Insertamos el valor tras la posición marcada por el entero "hueco"
    listaControl.insert(listaControl.begin() + hueco, bloqRestante);
}
```

---

Ejemplo de uso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print(std::vector<int> const &entrada)
{
    if (entrada.size() == 0) {
        std::cout << "-";
    } else {
        std::cout << entrada.at(0);
        for (std::vector<int>::size_type pos = 1, max = entrada.size(); pos < max; pos++) {
            std::cout << ' ' << entrada.at(pos);
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    /* Creamos un vector con contenido secuencial */
    std::vector<int> ejemplo = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    print(ejemplo);
    /* Agregamos el valor 6 en la tercera posición */
    ejemplo.insert(ejemplo.begin() + 3, 6);
    print(ejemplo);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilo y ejecuto:

```
g++ -Wall -g -pedantic prueba.cpp -o prueba && ./prueba
```

Dando como resultado:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 6 3 4 5
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda,  Saludos!!

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda. He agregado a mi respuesta un ejemplo de uso más sencillo, ya que no dispongo de tu código para poder  probar su buen funcionamiento. Por cierto, ¿quieres insertar un valor o sobreescribir el contenido?

Comment: Insertar un valor nada mas

Comment: ¿Cuando se genera este tipo de error a que se debe? error: no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type {aka int}' and 'std::vector<int>')

Comment: Es porque estás tratando de realizar la operación de suma entre dos tipos de datos que no son compatibles (te indica que tratas de sumar un `int` a un `std::vector<int>`). Abre nueva pregunta, comparte el código y te ayudamos.